# cannot change the Architectures in Xcode 5.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have a iOS project that compiles and work just fine on my macbook pro but when I try to run it from my iMac, it compiles just fine but crashes on an error that looks like this:

```
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x74c354
```

This method, I am calling from my appDelegate and it works just perfectly fine on my macbook pro. I thought it could be a problem with the Pods I am using but the settings are identical on my 2 machines. 
(same Podfile.lock, cocoapods 0.27.1, Ruby 2.0, Xcode 5.0.1 on both machines)

The only thing where I see a difference is that I can't configure the "architectures" on my iMac in the build settings. They don't even appear there at all. The same is true for the pods targets. (see image below)

[image]

Any idea on what could be wrong with my settings or environment?

Thanks!

Comment: You're viewing "basic." Hit "All"

Comment: I feel a little stupid :) You should write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch from the "Basic" view to the "All" view to see and change the architectures.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some temporary file in your project which is corrupted. close Xcode,  right click on the project file in the Finder, select Show Package Content, delete everything apart form project.pbxproj, try again.